# Microk8s trouble launching local docker image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microk8s, containerd

I'm using the latest version of microk8s and docker on the same VM. microk8s registry is enabled.

I restaged my image argus

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
argus                   0.1                 6d72b6be9981   3 hours ago   164MB
localhost:32000/argus   registry            6d72b6be9981   3 hours ago   164MB
```

then I pushed it

```
$ docker push localhost:32000/argus:registry
The push refers to repository [localhost:32000/argus]
c8a05c6fda3e: Pushed 
5836f564d6a0: Pushed 
9e3dd069b4a1: Pushed 
6935b1ceeced: Pushed 
d02e8e9f8523: Pushed 
c5129c726314: Pushed 
0f299cdf8fbc: Pushed 
edaf6f6a5ef5: Pushed 
9eb034f85642: Pushed 
043895432150: Pushed 
a26398ad6d10: Pushed 
0dee9b20d8f0: Pushed 
f68ef921efae: Pushed 
registry: digest: sha256:0a0ac9e076e3249b8e144943026bc7c24ec47ce6559a4e087546e3ff3fef5c14 size: 3052
```

all working seemingly fine but when I try to deploy a pod with:

```
$ microk8s kubectl create deployment argus --image=argus
deployment.apps/argus created
$ microk8s kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS         RESTARTS   AGE
argus-84c8dcc968-27nlz   0/1     ErrImagePull   0          9s
$ microk8s kubectl logs argus-84c8dcc968-27nlz
Error from server (BadRequest): container "argus" in pod "argus-84c8dcc968-27nlz" is waiting to start: trying and failing to pull image
```

The image can not be pulled, I tried the `$ microk8s ctr images ls` but this does not tell me anything.
So what is it that I'm doing wrong here?

**update:**

A bit of an update here when I try:

```
$ microk8s ctr image pull localhost:32000/argus:registry
ctr: failed to resolve reference "localhost:32000/argus:registry": failed to do request: Head "https://localhost:32000/v2/argus/manifests/registry": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

So it seems that it does not like that it gets and `http` response from my local repository. I looked into the config at `/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/containerd-template.toml` and there the `localhost` repository is correctly configured:

```
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]

    # 'plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors' are namespace to mirror mapping for all namespaces.
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
        endpoint = ["https://registry-1.docker.io", ]
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."localhost:32000"]
        endpoint = ["http://localhost:32000"]
```

I'm running all of this on a centos8 VM. When I installed docker
I needed to do it with `sudo dnf install docker-ce --nobest` because otherwise there was some kind of conflict with containerd maybe it has todo something with this?

Comment: What does `microk8s ctr images ls` return ?

Comment: I dug into it and there is one image called `docker.io/library/argus:0.1` in there, even though I'm pretty sure I did not push one to docker.io. If I try to pull it with `microk8s ctr image pull argus:0.1` it does not work and when I try  `microk8s ctr image pull localhost:32000/argus:0.1` I get the same http/https error. But I can launch a pod that goes into a crash restart loop `argus-d86987c57-9sdb2   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7          15m`.

Comment: Any progress with this issue ? Are there any details on why this image cannot be pulled when you describe the pod in `CrashLoopBackOff` state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there were multiple issues at play here, and I think I solved them all. First of, I made a mistake with the Docker Image. It was a test image, but it should have had something that continuously runs because after PID 1 ends the container gets restarted, the reasons is that `microk8s/kubernetes` assumes a there is a problem. That's why there was the crash loop.

Second, to check which repositories are present in the local registry, it's easiest to `curl` the `rest API` of the registry with:

```
$curl http://host:32000/v2/_catalog
```

to get a list of all images, and:

```
$curl http://host:32000/v2/{repositoryName}/tags/list
```

to get all tags for a given repo.

Lastly, to pull from the registry to the cluster manually without getting the `https` error, it's necessary to add the `--plain-http` option like this:

```
$microk8s ctr image pull --plain-http localhost:32000/repo:tag
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use kubectl describe to check the pod

i guess it try to pull the "argus" from docker.io

have you try add localhost:32000 to the image parameter?

```
microk8s kubectl create deployment argus --image=localhost:32000/argus:registry
```

Comment: Sadly, that does not work either. Yeah, I guess it's trying to pull the image from docker.io, but I want it pulled from local ... and seems it's either not registered with the local registry or in a cryptic name because I made a mistake ...

Comment: i see you set the tag to the local image, could you try the image --image=localhost:32000/argus:registry